# How to remove space on the corners of input

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the snippet, I've got spacing on the corners somehow. I need to remove spacing and make it look like a regular border. That's it

```css
form {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: solid #D3D8E0 1px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

input[type="email"] {
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 44px;
    background: #0CB66E;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
input[type="email"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" method="GET">
       <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
       <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Get started">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a `border-radius` on your input type email.

```css
form {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: solid #D3D8E0 1px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

input[type="email"] {
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 44px;
    background: #0CB66E;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
input[type="email"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" method="GET">
       <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
       <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Get started">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input[type="email"] has a border-radius of 0 so cuts through it. Change it to this:

```
input[type="email"] {
flex-grow: 2;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="email"] {
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
```